# trying to create a login view with grouped tableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview, authentication, storyboard

Trying to create a login screen like the one in the facebook app. Trying to do it with a grouped tableview with a button underneath. If I choose static cells I must enclose it in a tableview controller, but I don't want it to a table view controller since I want to put in other elements in the view. If I set it to Dynamic prototype the don't show up at all.

I'm doing this in the Storyboard interface.

Right now it looks like this in Storyboard:

```
ViewController
    View 
      TableView
       Table View Cell
       Table View Cell
      Button
```

Thanks.

Comment: why do you need to do this in a table view controller to begin with? for the rounded corners of a grouped table view?

Comment: I dont have it in a tableview controller right now, but for static cells its manadatory. (xcode gives and error)

Comment: What do you mean by static cells?

Comment: TableView->content. Can be set to static or dynamic prototype